# Jacoco index.html file is not generating coverage report for Maven testing without Spring boot/Sonar and showing "No class files specified" message

Tags: karate, jacoco-maven-plugin

Appended Jacoco plugin by referring to Karate document's POM.xml under ** Code Coverage using Jacoco section**. However, the coverage reports are not getting generated for feature files mentioned in the runner class upon running Maven test.

**Note:**

1. Using IntelliJ IDE with Maven.
2. 0.8.6 - Jacoco version and 3.0.0-M5 - Maven surefire.
3. Karate document mentions about Coverage profile but unable to find a sample coverage profile for reference purpose.
4. I'm performing QA testing and require coverage report for the Karate feature files.

I am new to creating coverage profile and generating Jacoco Coverage report.

Comment: honestly not sure, hope someone else here can help. refer other answers also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+jacoco

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you  please clarify on the 'Coverage profile' mentioned under Code Coverage using Jacoco in the Karate document?

Comment: sure. this is referring to a "maven profile". work with someone who knows maven if required. here is the link to where it is defined: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-demo/pom.xml#L152

Comment: @PeterThomas Project is built with Maven and referred to the same POM.xml in github. The Jacoco Coverage report detected runner class but not the feature files inside the runner class.  We are seeking a coverage report for the Karate feature files. Can you please confirm the feasibility on that?

Comment: coverage for karate feature files ? sorry I don't think that is possible, and I don't think that it makes sense either. the whole point of jacoco is to get coverage across your java code when you run your tests (if your back-end is java).